# Can't set source of video from React?

Tags: reactjs, video, wistia

I'm trying to dynamically update the source of a video component, I am using a video player package, React-player (see: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) in order to use Wistia video embeds because Wistia relies on having script tags/doesn't work well with React by itself.

Essentially I have a video source queue, and then when the video is done playing it goes to the next source on the queue. However I am getting the error: 
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.

I understand that other stackoverflows have said not to modify the media url directly, because it interferes with loading and modify the video.src instead... but that won't really work for me because I'm not using video tags/source tags/standard html5 player

Here is my code:

```
  class Videoplayer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            queue: ['https://home.wistia.com/medias/fi4s9gfe9']
        }
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        fetch("https://api.wistia.com/v1/medias.json?api_password="+apikey).then((res)=>{
            res.json().then((data)=>{
                let hashedqueue = [];
                data.forEach((vid)=>hashedqueue.push('https://home.wistia.com/medias/'+vid.hashed_id));
                this.setState({
                    queue: hashedqueue
                })          
            })
        })
    } 
  finishedPlaying() {
        this.player.playing = false;
        this.setState(prevState => {
          // make a shallow copy so as not to mutate state
          const videos = [...prevState.queue];
          videos.shift();
          return { queue: videos };
        });         
  }
    render(){   
        return(
        <div className="videoplayer">
            <ReactPlayer ref={player => { this.player = player }} onEnded={()=>this.finishedPlaying()}  url={this.state.queue[0]} playing />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use getInternalPlayer() for take the video tag in ReactPlayer , you can read more function in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player)